# WP "retrieve_password_message"

Tags: wordpress, square-bracket

do you happen to know how to remove those square brackets that come in the theme email template sent to users?

Thank you!

https://i.stack.imgur.com/g9VrO.jpg

Answer (score 0):

The bracket should contains your site name at Settings > General. Anyway you can change the email title by [retrieve_password_title](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/retrieve_password_title/) filter.

Example:

```
add_filter( 'retrieve_password_title', function( $title ) {
    return 'Hey! Your password has been changed';
});
```